# How to exit full screen mode in Atom Text Editor?

Tags: text-editor, fullscreen, atom

I just enabled Full screen mode in the Atom text editor and now I am unable to exit it, I saw [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjImIHe1J74) on YouTube but it didn't work for me. How can I fix this and exit fullscreen mode?

[image: Screenshot of fullscreen Atom text editor]

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works by pressing F11. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I tried F11 but nothing happened

Comment: Do other commands work for you, like Windows + D, which should get you back to your desktop? Or if you press Ctrl + Alt + T, can you see whether a new terminal is opened? It could just be that your laptop is frozen, and that this has nothing to do with Atom.

Comment: Does Fn + F11 work? @Sodead

Comment: YESSS IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!! Fn+F11

Comment: nah my laptop is not frozen, i am able to change virtual desktop, open apps and do everything

Comment: NOTE: if you installed the module platformio-ide-debugger (or some other packages), it overrides your F11 command. To check this you can serach for "f11" in Atom => Settings => Keybindings

Comment: @ZhanwenChen, you saved my day! Thanks so much. It was PlatformIO, that was overriding my F11 toggle full screen setting. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the module `platformio-ide-debugger` (or some other packages), it overrides your F11 command. To check this, you can sear for "f11" in Atom => Settings => Keybindings